Ebay response {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"}
When accessing the eBay API: Exchanging the authorization code for a User access token, I followed the documentation to make the request, but it always returns

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"}

My code is as follows:
    String keyEntity = "xxxxx:xxxxx";

    String encode = Base64.encode(keyEntity);

    String code = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    String decode = URLDecoder.decode(code, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(decode);

    String json = "grant_type=authorization_code&"+decode+"&"+"redirect_uri=xxxxxx";

    HttpResponse authorization = HttpRequest.post("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token").header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").header("Authorization", "Basic " + encode).body(json).execute();

I read the documentation, but I still can't figure out what the problem is.

Use [code block] format for multi line code.

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66504752/10832295

I don't think so, I've already decoded it this way
